# How can I Add or Update a ConcurrentDictionary, during a Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, concurrentdictionary

I have a list of files, where each file contains a list of `Foo` data. Now, the same piece of Foo data (eg. `Id = 1`) might exist in multiple files, but the more recent piece of data would overwrite an existing one.

I'm just reading each piece of data into an in memory collection.

```
if !cache.HasKey(foo.Id) then Add    
else cache[foo.Id].UpdatedOn < foo.UpdatedOn then Update  
else do nothing
```

When I'm reading in the files (because there's a few of them), I'm also using `Parallel.ForEach(files, file => { .. });`

I'm not sure how I do this.

I was thinking of using a `ConcurrentDictionary` but I wasn't sure how to do an `AddOrUpdate` with *where* clause thingy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `ConcurrentDictionary`, like so:

```
dictionary.AddOrUpdate(foo.Id, foo, (id, existing) => 
    existing.UpdatedOn < foo.UpdatedOn ? foo : existing);
```

Due to the discussion in the comments below, I will explain why there's no race condition here. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369) MSDN article discusses how value factories are run, and mentions that:

> Therefore, it is not guaranteed that the data that is returned by GetOrAdd is the same data that was created by the thread's valueFactory.

This makes sense, since the designers of the concurrent dictionary didn't want user code to lock the dictionary for who knows how long, rendering it useless. Instead, what `AddOrUpdate` does is run in two nested loops. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
do { 
   while (!TryGetValue(key, out value))
       if (TryAdd(key, addValue)) return;
   newValue = updateValueFactory(key, value);
} while (TryUpdate(key, newValue, value));
```

`TryUpdate` acquires the lock for the specific bucket, compares the current value to the retrieved value, and **only if they match** performs the update. If this fails, the outer loop happens again, `TryGetValue` returns the latest value, the value factory is called again, and so forth.

So it is assured that the value factory will always have the latest value if the update succeeds.

Comment: A race condition exists - to prevent, wrap the above code with a `lock( foo.Id )` block: "ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> is designed for multithreaded scenarios. You do not have to use locks in your code to add or remove items from the collection. However, it is always possible for one thread to retrieve a value, and another thread to immediately update the collection by giving the same key a new value." from MSDN "How to: Add and Remove Items from a ConcurrentDictionary"

Comment: @Moho, what race condition?

Comment: it is possible that two threads with the same `foo.Id` key value execute the `AddOrUpdate` method concurrently.

Comment: Ha, true.  Can't lock on an int.  There is a race condition, though.  Two threads with same `foo.Id` value but different `foo.UpdatedOn` values.  An older `UpdatedOn` could be updated after a later `UpdatedOn` value

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369
Read the first paragraph after the example code

Comment: second paragraph too - "not all methods are atomic, specifically GetOrAdd and AddOrUpdate"

Comment: Well I tested it and it does in fact prevent a race condition.  It will re-execute the `updateValueFactory` delegate if the value is changed during its execution.  I'll post test code in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Eli Arbel's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877631/how-can-i-add-or-update-this-net-collection-during-a-parallel-foreach/21878008#21878008) excellent answer, you could optimize the `AddOrUpdate` operation by using the overload that has a `TArg` generic type parameter. This way the `foo` will not be [captured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions) in a closure, reducing the pressure on the garbage collector:

```
dictionary.AddOrUpdate(foo.Id,
    (id, arg) => arg,
    (id, existing, arg) => existing.UpdatedOn < arg.UpdatedOn ? arg : existing,
    foo);
```

The signature of the advanced [`AddOrUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate#system-collections-concurrent-concurrentdictionary-2-addorupdate-1(-0-system-func((-0-0-1))-system-func((-0-1-0-1))-0)) overload:

```
public TValue AddOrUpdate<TArg>(
    TKey key,
    Func<TKey, TArg, TValue> addValueFactory,
    Func<TKey, TValue, TArg, TValue> updateValueFactory,
    TArg factoryArgument);
```

You can verify that nothing is captured by hovering the mouse over the [lambda operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) (`=>`) on Visual Studio.